# C++ MFC RegEx issue

Tags: c++, regex, mfc

I am using a Regex to restrict the some characters entered into a Textbox

I am using the below for the allowed characters

```
CAtlRegExp<> regex;
CString csText2 = "Some Test £"
CString m_szRegex = "([a-zA-Z0-9\\.\\,\";\\:'@#$£?\\+\\*\\-\\/\\%! ()])";
REParseError status = regex.Parse(m_szRegex, true);

CAtlREMatchContext<> mc;
if (!regex.Match(csText2, &mc)) 
{
     AfxMessageBox("Inavlid Char")
}
```

This works fine, except for the £ symbol. It doesn't seem to pick this up

Can anyone advise on what I am missing

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to be a bug that affects all Extended ASCII characters (those higher than 0x7F).

> The character value is converted to integer and used as an index into
>   some kind of attributes array. Since char is signed, it undergoes sign
>   expansion, so any character above 0x7F will cause an overflow.

```
size_t u = static_cast<size_t>(static_cast<_TUCHAR>(* ((RECHAR *) sz)));
if (pBits[u >> 3] & 1 << (u & 0x7))
```

You can find more discussions on this topic here: [CAtlRegExp crashes with pound sign!](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/microsoft.public.vc.atl/jrogllvlHCs.)